# How can I find out if this location is within the cropped area?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 2D matrix. I created a cropped region from this matrix. I have a position knowledge in my full size matrix. How can I find out if this location is within the cropped area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your matrix entries are position entries? If not, create two matrices x and y with size of your 2D matrix and take them as reference.

```
% create matrix
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:50);

% cropped matrix
x_crop = x(20:45,10:30);
y_crop = y(20:45,10:30);

% position in full-size matrix
pos = [25, 23]; % [x-coordinate, y-coordinate]

% get minimum and maximum positions of x_crop and y_crop
xmin = min(x_crop(:));
xmax = max(x_crop(:));

ymin = min(y_crop(:));
ymax = max(y_crop(:));

% Check if pos is inside minima/maxima
if pos(1)>= xmin && pos(1)<= xmax && pos(2)>=ymin && pos(2)<=ymax
   is_in = true;
else
   is_in = false;
end

is_in
```

Hope that helps. Hope also, I understood your question :D